# Can't see drafts folder in Mac Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have a recent MacBook Pro that was running OS X 10.6 but was recently updated to 10.7. My work email switched from Gmail to Exchange and they said to use the built-in Mail app. Overall, I like it, but I can't figure out how to see my drafts folder. According to the help, it only shows up if I have something in it, but I tried composing a message and saving it, and I still don't see my drafts folder in my list of folders. What am I supposed to do about this?

Comment: Which version of Exchange, it's pretty important to know the version and how the Exchange account is set up in Mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by restarting Mail. I have no idea why the drafts folder wasn't showing up before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in Mail preferences. Go to Preferences > Accounts > (account) > Mailbox Behaviors and enable Drafts.
[image: preferences]

If that doesn't work, show the Favorites Bar (View > Show Favorites Bar) and Drafts should be an option. Click it.
[image: favorites bar]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with an Exchange account in Mail app with Mac OS 10.7.3.
I got this when I save the message :

[image: Saving message]
Then I find it in the Draft folder (which were not here before) :

[image: Draft folder appears]

Did you try to quit Mail after you saved your message then reopen again ?
Check that you have this option enabled in your account preferences too :

[image]

Otherwise it could be an Exchange issue.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Same deal - I had the same issue then resolved by creating a new message, closing the message out, then saving it as a Draft. Magically my draft folder appeared. Problem solved. Not a great user experience though!

Answer (score -3):

Right Click -> Get Account Info->Drafts-Show Messages

You will be able to see drafts folder thereafter .

Cheers!!!

Ankur

Comment: How does this differ from let alone improve on http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46510/237